# Why group by is too slow in large data

Tags: python, pandas

I built up this code to group my data by total, month, week, day, hour, and 10 min. There is a problem when I want to run it in large data that has more than 20 million lines, it takes too long and did not finish even after 20 hours. I tried to split the file into small files but it is still slow.

Can you please check my code and is it possible to speed up the process?

```
def my_agg1(x):
  names = {
      'Total_in_averge_amount': x['value'].mean(),
      'Total_in_max_amount': x['value'].max(),
      'Total_in_min_amount': x['value'].min(),
      'Total_in_totalamount': x['value'].sum(),
      'Total_in_standard_deviation': x['value'].std(),
      'Total_in_degree': x['inputs'].sum(),
      'duration': x['date'].max() - x['date'].min()}
  return pd.Series(names, index=['Total_in_totalamount', 'Total_in_degree', 'Total_in_averge_amount', 'Total_in_max_amount', 'Total_in_min_amount', 'Total_in_standard_deviation', 'duration'])


# Read CSV File
df = pd.read_csv('inputs_header_2.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

# Total
groupTotal = df.groupby(['user']).apply(my_agg1)
c = abs(groupTotal['duration'].astype('timedelta64[D]'))
groupTotal['Total_in_standard_deviation'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
groupTotal['DurationInMin'] = (c * 24) * 60
TotalinDegree = groupTotal['Total_in_degree']
InTotalAmount = groupTotal['Total_in_totalamount']
InTransactionRate = (TotalinDegree / c)

groupTotal['Total_in_transaction_rate'] = round(InTransactionRate, 2)
groupTotal['Total_average_in_speed'] = InTotalAmount / c
Acceleration = (InTotalAmount / c ** 2)
groupTotal['Total_in-acceleration'] = Acceleration

groupTotal.replace(np.inf, 0, inplace=True)
groupTotal = groupTotal.drop(groupTotal.columns[[6]], axis=1)
#groupTotal.to_csv(r'fr1.csv', sep='\t', float_format='%.8f')
print(groupTotal)
groupTotal.to_csv(r'total.csv', sep='\t', float_format='%.8f')
# print(groupTotal)

#################################################################################

# Monthly
monthly_group_result = (df.set_index('date')
                        .groupby('user')
                        .resample('M', convention='start')
                        .agg({'value': ['mean', 'max', 'min', 'sum', 'std'],
                              'inputs': ['sum']}))
monthly_group_result.columns = monthly_group_result.columns.map('_'.join)

d_monthly = {'value_max': 'Monthly_in_max_amount',
             'value_min': 'Monthly_in_min_amount',
             'value_sum': 'Monthly_in_totalamount',
             'inputs_sum': 'Monthly_in_degree',
             'value_std': 'Monthly_in_standard_deviation',
             'value_mean': 'Monthly_in_averge_amount'}

monthly_group = monthly_group_result.rename(columns=d_monthly).reset_index()

['Monthly_in_degree'].transform('max') == group['Monthly_in_degree']]
MonthlygroupUser = monthly_group.loc[monthly_group.groupby('user')['Monthly_in_degree'].idxmax()]

MonthlygroupUser['Monthly_in_standard_deviation'].fillna('0', inplace=True)

MonthlyinDegree = MonthlygroupUser['Monthly_in_degree']
MonthlyInTotalAmount = MonthlygroupUser['Monthly_in_totalamount']
Monthly_date = MonthlygroupUser['date'].dt.daysinmonth
MonthlyInTransactionRate = (MonthlyinDegree / Monthly_date)
MonthlygroupUser['Monthly_in_transaction_rate'] = round(MonthlyInTransactionRate, 3)
MonthlygroupUser['Monthly_average_in_speed'] = MonthlyInTotalAmount / Monthly_date
MonthlyAcceleration = (MonthlyInTotalAmount / Monthly_date ** 2)

MonthlygroupUser['Monthly_in-acceleration'] = MonthlyAcceleration


MonthlygroupUser = MonthlygroupUser.drop(MonthlygroupUser.columns[[1, 5]], axis=1)


# Weekly

Weekly_group_result = (df.set_index('date')
                       .groupby('user')
                       .resample('7D', convention='start')
                       .agg({'value': ['mean', 'max', 'min', 'sum', 'std'],
                             'inputs': ['sum']}))
Weekly_group_result.columns = Weekly_group_result.columns.map('_'.join)

d_weekly = {'value_max': 'Weekly_in_max_amount',
            'value_min': 'Weekly_in_min_amount',
            'value_sum': 'Weekly_in_totalamount',
            'inputs_sum': 'Weekly_in_degree',
            'value_std': 'Weekly_in_standard_deviation',
            'value_mean': 'Weekly_in_averge_amount'}

Weeklygroup = Weekly_group_result.rename(columns=d_weekly).reset_index()

WeeklygroupUser = Weeklygroup.loc[Weeklygroup.groupby('user')['Weekly_in_degree'].idxmax()]

WeeklygroupUser['Weekly_in_standard_deviation'].fillna('0', inplace=True)

WeeklyinDegree = WeeklygroupUser['Weekly_in_degree']
WeeklyInTotalAmount = WeeklygroupUser['Weekly_in_totalamount']
WeeklyInTransactionRate = (WeeklyinDegree / 7)
WeeklygroupUser['Weekly_in_transaction_rate'] = round(WeeklyInTransactionRate, 3)
WeeklygroupUser['Weekly_average_in_speed'] = WeeklyInTotalAmount / 7
WeeklyAcceleration = (WeeklyInTotalAmount / 7 ** 2)

WeeklygroupUser['Weekly_in-acceleration'] = WeeklyAcceleration


WeeklygroupUser = WeeklygroupUser.drop(WeeklygroupUser.columns[[1, 4]], axis=1)


# daily

Daily_group_result = (df.set_index('date')
                      .groupby('user')
                      .resample('D', convention='start')
                      .agg({'value': ['mean', 'max', 'min', 'sum', 'std'],
                            'inputs': ['sum']}))
Daily_group_result.columns = Daily_group_result.columns.map('_'.join)

d_daily = {'value_max': 'Daily_in_max_amount',
           'value_min': 'Daily_in_min_amount',
           'value_sum': 'Daily_in_totalamount',
           'inputs_sum': 'Daily_in_degree',
           'value_std': 'Daily_in_standard_deviation',
           'value_mean': 'Daily_in_averge_amount'}

Dailygroup = Daily_group_result.rename(columns=d_daily).reset_index()
DailygroupUser = Dailygroup.loc[Dailygroup.groupby('user')['Daily_in_degree'].idxmax()]

DailygroupUser['Daily_in_standard_deviation'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
DailyinDegree = DailygroupUser['Daily_in_degree']
DailyInTotalAmount = DailygroupUser['Daily_in_totalamount']
DailyInTransactionRate = (DailyinDegree / 1)
DailygroupUser['Daily_in_transaction_rate'] = round(DailyInTransactionRate, 3)
DailygroupUser['Daily_average_in_speed'] = DailyInTotalAmount / 1
DailyAcceleration = (DailyInTotalAmount / 1 ** 2)

DailygroupUser['Daily_in-acceleration'] = DailyAcceleration


DailygroupUser = DailygroupUser.drop(DailygroupUser.columns[[1, 4]], axis=1)

# Hourly


# group all users by hour
Hourly_group_result = (df.set_index('date')
                       .groupby('user')
                       .resample('H', convention='start')
                       .agg({'value': ['mean', 'max', 'min', 'sum', 'std'],
                             'inputs': ['sum']}))
Hourly_group_result.columns = Hourly_group_result.columns.map('_'.join)

d_hourly = {'value_max': 'Hourly_in_max_amount',
            'value_min': 'Hourly_in_min_amount',
            'value_sum': 'Hourly_in_totalamount',
            'inputs_sum': 'Hourly_in_degree',
            'value_std': 'Hourly_in_standard_deviation',
            'value_mean': 'Hourly_in_averge_amount'}

Hourlygroup = Hourly_group_result.rename(columns=d_hourly).reset_index()
HourlygroupUser = Hourlygroup.loc[Hourlygroup.groupby('user')['Hourly_in_degree'].idxmax()]
)
HourlygroupUser['Hourly_in_standard_deviation'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
HourlyinDegree = HourlygroupUser['Hourly_in_degree']
HourlyInTotalAmount = HourlygroupUser['Hourly_in_totalamount']
HourlyInTransactionRate = (HourlyinDegree / (1 / 24))
HourlygroupUser['Hourly_in_transaction_rate'] = round(HourlyInTransactionRate, 3)
HourlygroupUser['Hourly_average_in_speed'] = HourlyInTotalAmount / 1
HourlyAcceleration = (HourlyInTotalAmount / (1 / 24) ** 2)

HourlygroupUser['Hourly_in-acceleration'] = HourlyAcceleration


HourlygroupUser = HourlygroupUser.drop(HourlygroupUser.columns[[1, 4]], axis=1)



# group all users by 10Min
TenMin_group_result = (df.set_index('date')
                       .groupby('user')
                       .resample('10Min', convention='start')
                       .agg({'value': ['mean', 'max', 'min', 'sum', 'std'],
                             'inputs': ['sum']}))
TenMin_group_result.columns = TenMin_group_result.columns.map('_'.join)

d_10Min = {'value_max': 'TenMin_in_max_amount',
           'value_min': 'TenMin_in_min_amount',
           'value_sum': 'TenMin_in_totalamount',
           'inputs_sum': 'TenMin_in_degree',
           'value_std': 'TenMin_in_standard_deviation',
           'value_mean': 'TenMin_in_averge_amount'}

TenMingroup = TenMin_group_result.rename(columns=d_10Min).reset_index()
TenMingroupUser = TenMingroup.loc[TenMingroup.groupby('user')['TenMin_in_degree'].idxmax()]
TenMingroupUser['TenMin_in_standard_deviation'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
TenMininDegree = TenMingroupUser['TenMin_in_degree']
TenMinInTotalAmount = TenMingroupUser['TenMin_in_totalamount']
TenMinInTransactionRate = (TenMininDegree / (1 / 24 / 6))
TenMingroupUser['TenMin_in_transaction_rate'] = round(TenMinInTransactionRate, 3)
TenMingroupUser['TenMin_average_in_speed'] = TenMinInTotalAmount / (1 / 24 / 6)
TenMinAcceleration = ((TenMinInTotalAmount / (1 / 24 / 6) ** 2)) - (1 / 24 / 6)

TenMingroupUser['TenMin_in-acceleration'] = TenMinAcceleration


TenMingroupUser = TenMingroupUser.drop(TenMingroupUser.columns[[1, 4]], axis=1)
#TenMingroupUser.to_csv(r'fr1.csv', sep='\t', float_format='%.8f')




FinalTotal = pd.merge(groupTotal, MonthlygroupUser, on='user').merge(WeeklygroupUser, on='user').merge(DailygroupUser, on='user').merge(HourlygroupUser, on='user').merge(TenMingroupUser, on='user')

FinalTotal.to_csv(r'Final_Inputs_2.csv', sep='\t', float_format='%.8f', index=False)
```

Thank you for any help

Regards,

Khaled

Comment: Ok, this might be a sign, that ```pandas``` alone is not a best technology for your use case. I would either try mixing pandas with some caching on disk mechanism (e.g. in SQLite) so you don't do everything in memory or try exploring possibility of using ```pyspark```.

Comment: try to research [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/)